# Loading select options from remote site using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My html:

```
<div id="body" ng-controller="ClientController">    
    <select kendo-drop-down-list>
        <option data-ng-repeat="client in Clients">{{ client.Name }}</option>
    </select>
    <button data-ng-click="loadClients()">Load Clients</button>
    <pre>http response data: {{ data }}</pre>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/index")
```

And my javascript:

```
function ClientController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.url = "/tracker/api/client";
    $scope.selectedClient = null;
    $scope.Clients = null;
    $scope.loadClients = function () {
        $http.get($scope.url).then(function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data;
            $scope.Clients = response.data;
        });
    };
 }
```

When I click the button, I retrieve a bunch of json from my webapi server- this data displays okay in the response data section- but my dropdown is always empty.  The HTML page shows this:

```
<option value="? object:null ?"></option>
```

Which I take means I am not getting data set properly.  I'm obviously an angular n00b :) what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the ng-options directive.

Example:

```
<select ng-model="selectedClient" ng-options="client.name for client in Clients">
```

Here is more info. The usage of ng-options is a bit different for arrays vs objects and there are a few different ways to use it, but there's a little somethin' for everyone: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: I don't know why, but I cant get this to work... if I do this: `<ul><li data-ng-repeat="client in Clients">{{ client.Name }}</li></ul>` I see the list of clients just fine.  But `<select kendo-drop-down-list ng-options="client.Name for client in Clients"></select>` still shows nothing...

Comment: Yes the kendo thing takes the select and tries to make it out of a <ul> which clashes with what angular tries to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but someone might find this helpful when working with kendo and restful services.

One way to go is using `k-rebind`, it could look like this (I haven't tested it):

```
    <select kendo-drop-down-list k-rebind="Clients.length">
      <option data-ng-repeat="client in Clients">{{ client.Name }}</option>
    </select>
```

You may experiment with `k-rebind="Clients"` even. It basicaly reinits kendo widget for you when a variable or object changes.
Source: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction

If you don't need to display the dropdown before data is loaded. Try using `ng-if`, which in some cases delays kendo:

```
    <select kendo-drop-down-list ng-if="Clients.length > 0">
      <option data-ng-repeat="client in Clients">{{ client.Name }}</option>
    </select>
```